# Hope solving ; ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg

Tags: symbols

Whenever I tried to make a pdf document, this issue occurred.
How could I deal with this?
I'm very embarrassed by the problem!

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Comparison of Regression Results} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-4} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Corruption} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 GDP per capita & 0.0002^{***}$ $(0.0002$, $0.0002) &  &  \\ 
  GDP per capita (Squred) &  & 0.000^{***}$ $(0.000$, $0.000) &  \\ 
  GDP per capital (Log) &  &  & 1.431^{***}$ $(1.255$, $1.606) \\ 
  Constant & 2.502^{***}$ $(2.259$, $2.746) & 3.413^{***}$ $(3.154$, $3.671) & -8.114^{***}$ $(-9.621$, $-6.607) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{170} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{170} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{170} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

*ADD Syntax*

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(q4_fit, q4_fit_squred, q4_g_log, type="latex",
          title ="Comparison of Regression Results", align=TRUE, 
          dep.var.labels="Corruption",
          covariate.labels=c("GDP per capita", "GDP per capita (Squred)", "GDP per capital (Log)"),
          keep.stat="n", ci=TRUE, ci.level=0.95, single.row=TRUE)
```

Comment: the actual error message would say which character was illegal, presumably `D` which is not a standard column type. You have not provided an example that produces the error but perhaps you are missing `\usepackage{dcolumn}`

Answer (score 2):

The error messags is due to the array column specifier `D` which you have used and not defined (I guess as you neither showed the full error or a test document)

You are using the syntax of the `dcolumn` package and simply loading that package makes the error go away although the `-3` specification makes very wide table here that is unlikely to fit your (unspecified) page size.

I guess you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} \centering 
  \caption{Comparison of Regression Results} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{lD{.}{.}{1.7}l D{.}{.}{1.7}l D{.}{.}{1.7}l } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Corruption} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 GDP per capita & 0.0002^{***}& (0.0002, 0.0002) & & &&  \\ 
  GDP per capita (Squared) & & & 0.000^{***}&(0.000, 0.000) &&  \\ 
  GDP per capital (Log) & & & & & 1.431^{***}&(1.255, 1.606) \\ 
  Constant & 2.502^{***}&(2.259, 2.746) & 3.413^{***}&(3.154, 3.671) & -8.114^{***}&(-9.621, -6.607) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{2}{c}{170} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{170} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{170} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CSKim It's better to ask new questions as new questions, instead of followups hiding in comments.  The preamble is everything that comes before `\begin{document}`.  The `\usepackage` command can only be used there.